# Why the dangling pointer is giving the size of the previously pointed variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, dangling-pointer

```
class B
{
public:
    B():a(0), b(0) { }
    B(int x):a(x), b(0) { }
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class A
{
public:
    A(B* ptr):pB(ptr) { }
    void modifypB() 
    { 
        delete pB; 
        pB = NULL; 
    }
    void printBSize() 
    { 
        if( pB != NULL )
            cout<<"pB pointing to Obj size:"<<sizeof(*pB)<<endl; 
        else
            cout<<"pB pointing to Obj size:"<<sizeof(*pB)<<endl; 
    }

private:
    B *pB;
};


void main()
{
    B *bObj = new B(10);
    cout<<"Size of bObj:"<<sizeof(*bObj)<<endl;

    A aObj(bObj);
    cout<<"Size of aObj:"<<sizeof(aObj)<<endl;

    cout<<"Before De-allocating: ";
    aObj.printBSize();
    aObj.modifypB();
    cout<<"After De-allocating: ";
    aObj.printBSize();
}
```

Output:

```
Size of bObj: 8
Size of aObj: 4
Before De-allocating: pB pointing to Obj size: 8
After De-allocating: pB pointing to Obj size: 8
```

Why the size of `*pB` is 8, even after de-allocation ?

Comment: Just because you `delete` the pointer and set the value of the pointer equal to `NULL` doesn't mean the memory it's pointing to has been changed at all.  You just have undefined behavior.

Comment: Its just like when you delete a file.  deleting the file does nothing but remove the listing of that file from the file table.  It is still there on the harddrive until you overwrite it.

Comment: What did you expect instead?

Comment: @dwcanillas: It's not even UB. `sizeof` uses the static type of the expression, without evaluating it; so it's defined to be `sizeof(B)` whatever the pointer's value.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yeah, I didnt read his question close enough, but I chose to leave my comment anyway.  My comment is related to the question he was asking, but not to the behavior in his example.

Answer (score 4):

> Why the size of *pB is 8, even after de-allocation ?

`sizeof(*pB)` is evaluated at compile time based on the type of `*pB`. Its value does not depend on the value of `pB` at run time.

You are printing `sizeof(B)` in both branches of your `if` statement, which is `8` on your platform.

Comment: How to determine pB is pointing to NULL at run time?

Comment: `if ( pB == NULL )`.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(*p)` gives you the size of the object which the compiler has determined at compile-time and not at runtime.

Try this:

```
int main(void)
{
     std::string *string_pointer = 0;
     std::cout  << sizeof(*string_pointer) << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

This will not segfault but print the size of the `std::string`-class.

Comment: How to determine that pB is pointing to NULL at run time?

Comment: `if (pB == NULL) cout << "pB is pointing to NULL\n";` - for more questions please create new ones. But always start with an internet/stackoverflow-search